# NPE caused by Modena.class.getResource("TestApp.css")

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to run the java-fx sample Modena that can be found [here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). I use Netbeans 8.0 Beta, JDK8 last release on Windows 8. I wonder why I can't even compile it.

In fact the first exception that happens is this.

I note to be a newbie in JavaFX.

The line of exception in the program is:

```
private static final String testAppCssUrl = Modena.class.getResource("TestApp.css").toExternalForm();
```

I assert that I verified and the file existed. And the example jar file can be run on my computer with my Java default configuration which is explained above.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$2.run(LauncherImpl.java:330) at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$2.run(LauncherImpl.java:330)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:331) at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:331)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modena.Modena.<clinit>(Modena.java:100)
    ... 13 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:362)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: getResource("TestApp.css") is returning a NULL.  So you get an NPE.  You have just feed it a file name, but it is probably going to need the actual file path to load the file.

Comment: @BrianC No, changing the path to the complete one didn't work. The problem was with running with Shift+F6 instead of F6 as I have told in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with running only the main file with `Shift+F6`. I should have used `F6` to run the project instead. `F6` runs the project but `Shift+F6` only runs the file containing the static main method without considering the project configuration.